# How do I update C# using developer command prompt?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We are not allowed to use Visual Studio in our school, we have to write them in Notepad++ and then compile them using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 using `csc`.

I get a bunch of problems in my personal computer than I don't get in my school computer because of my outdated C# version. How do I update it using, preferably, the Developer Command Prompt?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: using System;

// any code, doesn't matter (no namespace or sth like that)

Comment: what else is in file?

Comment: Like I said, doesn't matter but okay


using System;
Console.WriteLine("something");


That's a simple case of the same error happening

Comment: Where did you get the command line compiler from? There is probably an update available there.

Comment: I don't know sorry

Answer (score 0):

The C# language feature you're trying to use is called [Top Level Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements), which was introduced with C# 9.

In order to compile for C# 9 you'll need to install the latest .net SDK.

You'll probably want to install [the .net 5.0 64-bit SDK from this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). (It does say that "Visual Studio 2019" is required on the download page, but it doesn't mean that you need to have Visual Studio installed - your command-line builds will work fine.)

Comment: I just installed it, but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Ascyt Are you sure the computer is using the correct version of csc? You can use `csc /?` to get the version number of the csc that is being called.

Comment: I don't know how to update it, the entire point of this question is me asking how to update...